# WordPress add script with custom type (x-jquery-tmpl)

Tags: filters, jquery, wp-enqueue-script, custom-header

I would like to a add the following script into WordPress:

```
<script type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">  
  ...
</script>
```

but using:

```
wp_add_inline_script( 'my-script', '...' );
```

will give me:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
  ...
</script>
```

Must I edit `header.php` for any type of script that is not javascript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Printing the script in the head is a method called `do_item` in the [`wp_script`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_scripts/) class. In this method you see this line:

```
$tag = "{$cond_before}{$before_handle}<script type='text/javascript' src='$src'></script>\n{$after_handle}{$cond_after}";
```

So, the script type is hardwired in the function. However, a few lines further on, you see this:

```
$tag = apply_filters( 'script_loader_tag', $tag, $handle, $src );
```

This allows you to build a filter to change the script type. First you would enqueue your script file [in the usual way](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/):

```
wp_enqueue_script ('my-script-handle', 'http://.../my-script.js');
```

Then you would define a filter that changes the script type for this specific script:

```
add_filter ('script_loader_tag', wpse262406_change_script_type, 10, 3);
function wpse262406_change_script_type ($tag, $handle, $src) {
  if ($handle == 'my-script-handle')
    $tag = str_replace ('text/javascript', 'text/x-jquery-tmpl', $tag);
  return $tag;
  }
```

Note: I didn't test this code, so some debugging might be necessary.

Comment: yea, it was not working when your preg_replace() was not assigned to anything.